# Minishop2 модальное окно Modx revo

Tags: javascript, html, modx, minishop2

пытаюсь вывести информацию о товаре в модальном окне, но ничего не выводит, пишет

```
[msGallery] The resource with id = 9 is not instance of msProduct.
```

вот кнопка

```
<div class="action-view">
            <button type="button" class="btn" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Просмотр</button>
          </div>
```

вот само модальное окно

```
<div id="quickview-wrapper">
```

[[!wayRowTpl]]
        
          ×
        
        
          
            
              
                [[!msGallery]]

```
        <div class="product-info">
          <h1>[[*pagetitle]]</h1>
          <div class="price-box">
            <p class="price"><span class="special-price"><span class="amount"><b> [[+price]] [[%ms2_frontend_currency]]</b></span></span></p>
          </div>
          <p class="availability in-stock">Наличие: 
            [[*avaible:eq=`1`:then=`<span>В наличии</span>`]]
            [[*avaible:eq=`2`:then=`<span>Под заказ</span>`]]
            [[*avaible:eq=`0`:then=`<span>Нет в наличии</span>`]]
          </p>
          <a href="product-details.html" class="see-all">Перейти к товару</a>
          <div class="quick-add-to-cart">
            <form method="post" class="cart">
              <div class="add-to-box add-to-box2">
                <div class="add-to-cart">
                  <div class="input-content">
                    <label for="qty">Количество:</label>
                    <input type="button" class="qty-decrease" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) &amp;&amp; qty &gt; 0 ) qty_el.value--;return false;" value="-">
                    <!--<input type="text" class="input-text qty" title="Qty" value="1" maxlength="12" id="qty" name="qty">-->
                    <input type="number" name="count" id="product_price" maxlength="12" class="input-text qty" value="1"/>
                    <input type="button" class="qty-increase" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) qty_el.value++;return false;" value="+">
                  </div>
                  [[*avaible:neq=`0`:then=`
                  <button type="submit" class="btn" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add"><span>Добавить в корзину</span></button>`]]
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="quick-desc">
            [[*description]]
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тебе же ясно написано что ресурс с айдишником 9 не msProduct в чём проблема разобраться?

Comment: я недавно начал работать с minishop2, а как сделать тогда или куда лезть?